# why this script is not working??? -div show up depend on scroll height

Tags: javascript

i wanna make two div box show up when i scroll down
so "couponimg_box" show up when i scroll down 300

and "couponimg_box2" show up when it was 800.

"couponimg_box" is working now
but the problem is "couponimg_box2" is not working....

is there any way to fix this???
any help will be so appreciate!
thanks!

```js
myID1 = document.getElementById("coupon_box");
myID2 = document.getElementById("coupon_box2");

var myScrollFunc = function() {
  var y = window.scrollY;
  if (y >= 300) {
    myID1.className = "couponimg_box show"
  } else {
    myID1.className = "couponimg_box hide"
  }

  if (y >= 800) {
    myID2.className = "couponimg_box2 show"
  } else {
    myID2.className = "couponimg_box2 hide"
  }
};

window.addEventListener("scroll", myScrollFunc);
```

Comment: You should add some html code so snippet can run and people can see current result inplace.

Comment: Also did you check whethere class name of `myID2` has changed?

Comment: oh;;;tou are right..... thanks!